# stm32f103c8t6 USART1 interrupt doesn't work

Tags: c, stm32

Good Day.
I'm trying to run UART example script from Stm32 std library, and it seems it doesn't work.
I'm using such board: [image]

Upload firmware via USART1.
USART init code:

```
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include <misc.h>

volatile char received_string[MAX_STRLEN+1];

void Delay(__IO uint32_t nCount) {
  while(nCount--) {
  }
}

void init_USART1(uint32_t baudrate){

   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct;
   USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStruct;
   NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA, ENABLE);


   GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_9;
   GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
   GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

   GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
   GPIO_InitStruct.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING; 
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

   USART_InitStruct.USART_BaudRate = baudrate;
   USART_InitStruct.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
   USART_InitStruct.USART_StopBits = USART_StopBits_1;
   USART_InitStruct.USART_Parity = USART_Parity_No;
   USART_InitStruct.USART_HardwareFlowControl =    USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
   USART_InitStruct.USART_Mode = USART_Mode_Tx | USART_Mode_Rx;
   USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStruct);

   USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);


   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel = USART1_IRQn;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority = 0;
   NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd = ENABLE;  
   NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);      

   USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);
}

void USART_puts(USART_TypeDef* USARTx, volatile char *s){

   while(*s){
      while( !(USARTx->SR & 0x00000040) );
      USART_SendData(USARTx, *s);
      *s++;
   }
}

int main(void) {

  init_USART1(9600); // initialize USART1 @ 9600 baud

  USART_puts(USART1, "Init complete! Hello World!\r\n"); // just send a message to indicate that it works

   while (1){
     /*
      * You can do whatever you want in here
      */
   }
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(void){

    // check if the USART1 receive interrupt flag was set
    if( USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) ){

        static uint8_t cnt = 0; // this counter is used to determine the string length
        char t = USART1->DR; // the character from the USART1 data register is saved in t

        // check if the received character is not the LF character (used to determine end of string)
        // or the if the maximum string length has been been reached
        if( (t != '\n') && (cnt < MAX_STRLEN) ){
            received_string[cnt] = t;
            cnt++;
        }
         else{ // otherwise reset the character counter and print the received string
           cnt = 0;
           USART_puts(USART1, received_string);
        }
    }
}
```

USART1 port is working wothout NVIC enabling.

Comment: Where do you have the interrupt handlers?

Comment: Bottom of the file.
void USART1_IRQHandler(void){
 ....
}

Comment: https://github.com/nmuntyanov/stm32-test/blob/master/src/main.c
Take a look here

Comment: No github etc. please.  We don't like external links that can go stale.  If it's needed it should be in the SO question.

Comment: Also, debugging embedded stuff, especially where drivers are involved, is best left to someone who has the hardware, compiler, linker, debugger, environment, test equipment etc.   'Debugging' by exchanging text on a website is likely to be unproductive.

Comment: I'm new in MC programming. So, I'm hoping that someone had this problem before, and can give me an answer.

Comment: What a problem like 'UART not working'?  Untold thousands have had this problem before, for many, many different reasons.

Comment: @Nicollo if you're new to microcontroller programming, have you tried getting started with arduino (available for your your uC: http://wiki.stm32duino.com/index.php?title=Blue_Pill ) or interfacing your device using the manufacturer drivers (high level HAL or low level LL drivers)?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit You have nothing to say for help me, so you just want to tell something, no matter what?

Comment: @Lanting Yes, I'm trying to run manufacturer example, from standard peripheral library. I have no my own code there. After MC initialization - it sends string to USART, I can read it in Putty, but I can't send anything back,  Interrupt doesn't happens

Comment: @Nicollo SO is not a help centre.  I just want to tell you that it's unreasonable to ask for help with embedded inerrupt handlers via some text exchange when you have the text, the compiler, the linker, the debugger, the environment etc.  You did not even post all the relevant code and data, merely the UART and VIC init. code that references #defines that are not shown.   How is that going to be useful to future users/visitors?

Comment: Does the UART0 interrupt work?

Comment: Do any interrupts work, eg, from timers?

Comment: How do you know that the interrupt is not happening?

Comment: Is it the tx or rx interrupt that does not work, or both?

Comment: @ThingyWotsit Updated my question, added full code

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I've added "USART_SendData" top of USART1_IRQHandler, and nothing was happend, after i send a byte

Comment: I've tried to change:  if( USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) ) { ECHO received byte } also.

Comment: Checked USART2  - not work aswell

Answer (score 0):

Could you try changing your USART_puts() function to:

```
void USART_puts(USART_TypeDef* USARTx, volatile char *s){
    while(*s)
    {
      while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET);// Wait the set of TXE
      USART_SendData(USART1, *(s++));
      while(USART_GetFlagStatus(USART1, USART_FLAG_TC) == RESET);// Wait the end of transmit
    }
}
```

Comment: Has no effect. Did as you recommended.

Comment: Changed Int handler to led on/off  after receiving byte.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Stdpriph methods like you. My code works. Can you give it a try mate?

```
#include <stm32f10x.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stm32f10x_usart.h>
#include <stm32f10x_gpio.h>
#include <stm32f10x_rcc.h>


static unsigned int LEDState = 0;


static void USART_SendString(USART_TypeDef* USARTx, char* s)
{
    while(*s)
    {
    while(!USART_GetFlagStatus(USARTx, USART_FLAG_TC));
    USART_SendData(USARTx, *s);
    s++;
}
  }




void USART1_IRQHandler(void)
{
    if(USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) != RESET)
  {

    if((char)USART_ReceiveData(USART1) == '1'){
        LEDState = 2;
            GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0, Bit_SET);


            }

    if((char)USART_ReceiveData(USART1) == '0')
        LEDState = 1;
            GPIO_WriteBit(GPIOA, GPIO_Pin_0, Bit_RESET);
}
USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE);
 }




  int main(){

   SystemInit();
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
   USART_InitTypeDef USART_InitStructure;
 USART_ClockInitTypeDef USART_ClockInitStructure; 
  NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------  

   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOA | RCC_APB2Periph_AFIO, ENABLE); 
   RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_USART1, ENABLE);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_Pin_8;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed   = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOC, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode=GPIO_Mode_AF_PP;
   GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin     = GPIO_Pin_9 ;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed   = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
   GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_10;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN_FLOATING; 
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

USART_InitStructure.USART_BaudRate = 115200;
USART_InitStructure.USART_WordLength = USART_WordLength_8b;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Parity                = USART_Parity_No;
USART_InitStructure.USART_StopBits              = USART_StopBits_1;
USART_InitStructure.USART_HardwareFlowControl   = USART_HardwareFlowControl_None;
USART_InitStructure.USART_Mode                  = USART_Mode_Tx | USART_Mode_Rx;

USART_Init(USART1, &USART_InitStructure);
USART_ITConfig(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE, ENABLE);
USART_Cmd(USART1, ENABLE);

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel          = USART1_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd       = ENABLE;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority=0;
        NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelSubPriority=0;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);





  //GPIO
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0; //GPIOA pin 0 output push pull
  GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
  GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);





       /*   GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;



        TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef TIM3_InitStructure;
        NVIC_InitTypeDef NVIC_InitStructure;

      RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB2Periph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
      RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(RCC_APB1Periph_TIM3, ENABLE);


     GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_Out_PP;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin=GPIO_Pin_12;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed= GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);

TIM3_InitStructure.TIM_Prescaler         = 50 ; //Prescaler degeri.
TIM3_InitStructure.TIM_CounterMode       = TIM_CounterMode_Up; //Timer yukari sayacak sekilde ayarlandi.
TIM3_InitStructure.TIM_Period            = 48000;//Period degeri.
TIM3_InitStructure.TIM_ClockDivision     = TIM_CKD_DIV1;//Bölme orani 1 yani geçersiz-kapali.
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &TIM3_InitStructure);//Ayarlari yükle
TIM_ITConfig(TIM3, TIM_IT_Update, ENABLE); // Kesmeyi aktif ediyoruz.

NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannel          = TIM3_IRQn;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority =0;
NVIC_InitStructure.NVIC_IRQChannelCmd       = ENABLE;
NVIC_Init(&NVIC_InitStructure);

 TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);*/





while(1)
{
    char temp= USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
    /*if(LEDState == 2) {
        GPIO_SetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_8);
        USART_SendString(USART1, "LED On\r\n");
        LEDState = 0;
    }
    if(LEDState == 1) {
        GPIO_ResetBits(GPIOC, GPIO_Pin_8);
        USART_SendString(USART1, "LED Off\r\n");
        LEDState = 0;
    }
}*/




    }
```

}